# Athena top 1 result from each group

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, amazon-athena, row-number

is there any way to implement top 1 result from each group without using ROW_NUMBER?
table_a below has already 1 billion rows, so I want to use the most efficient way.

And the below query is what I'm using.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column_a, column_b, column_c ORDER BY column_d) AS row_num,
               *
        FROM   table_a
        )
WHERE  row_num = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `group by` and the aggregate function `min()` :

```
SELECT column_a, column_b, column_c, min(column_d) as top1
FROM table_a
group by column_a, column_b, column_c
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would by `distinct on`. However `distinct on` is a Postgres extension and not a SQL standard.

```
select distinct on (column_a, column_b, column_c) 
       column_a, column_b, column_c, column_d as top1
  from table_a
 order by column_a, column_b, column_c, column_d;
```